# Is the extension of every undecidable theory undecidable?

Tags: computability, logic, undecidability, closure-properties

While it is not the case that the extension of every decidable theory is decidable, is it true that:

the extension of every undecidable theory undecidable?

In other words, given an undecidable theory A, is it enough to show

$$A \subseteq B$$

to prove that B is undecidable?

Comment: Cross-posted to [computer science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33781/9550) and [CS theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/27681/17082). Please do not do this. It is against site policy because it fragments answers and wastes people's time when they work on something that has already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Properties like undecidability tend to *never* be closed against sub- or superset. $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are trivial counter-examples to any such claim.

Answer (score 3):

No. A theory is a set of theorems. The set of all formulas is a decidable theory and it is an extension of all theories, including undecidable ones. It is also very inconsistent and thus useless in practice, but it is a counter-example to your claim.